# Decorator Pattern with method relation

Tags: php, symfony, decorator

I use the design pattern Decorator in PHP, and I've got a structure problem.

Here's a simple example to illustrate my problem :

```
interface MyInterface {
    function showUsers($array);
    function showUser($i);
}

class MyCLass implements MyInterface {

    function showUsers($array)
    {
        foreach($array as $toto) {
            $this->showUser($toto);
        }
    }

    function showUser($i)
    {
        echo $i;
    }
}

class MyCLassDecorator implements MyInterface {

    private $inner;

    public function __construct(MyInterface $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    function showUsers($array)
    {
        $this->inner->showUsers($array);
    }

    function showUser($i)
    {
        echo "User: $i";
    }
}

class MyCLassDecorator2 implements MyInterface {

    private $inner;

    public function __construct(MyInterface $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    function showUsers($array)
    {
        $this->inner->showUsers($array);
    }

    function showUser($i)
    {
        $this->inner->showUser($i);
        echo " is wonderful";
    }
}

$myClass = new MyCLassDecorator2(new MyCLassDecorator(new MyCLass()));

$myClass->showUsers(["Alfred", "Bob", "Claire"]);
```

With this code, the methods showUser of MyClassDecorator & MyClassDecorator2 will never be called.

What can I do?
Is it forbidden to call another method of the same class? (Not really convenient to split my code)
Is there another way to do this?
Should I create one interface by method ?

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT:

Here is the solution that I finally used, although I'm not really satisfied of it...

I split my code not in methods but in interfaces(services)

Here it is :

```
interface IShowUsers {
    function showUsers($array);
}
interface IShowUser {
    function showUser($user);
}

class Services {
    static $showUsers;
    static $showUser;
}

class MyShowUsers implements IShowUsers {

    function showUsers($array)
    {
        foreach($array as $toto) {
            Services::$showUser->showUser($toto);
        }
    }
}

class MyShowUser implements IShowUser {
    function showUser($user)
    {
        echo $user;
    }
}

class MyShowUserDecorator implements IShowUser {

    private $inner;

    public function __construct(IShowUser $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    function showUser($user)
    {
        echo "User: ";
        $this->inner->showUser($user)
    }
}

class MyShowUserDecorator2 implements IShowUser {

    private $inner;

    public function __construct(MyInterface $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    function showUser($user)
    {
        $this->inner->showUser($user);
        echo " is wonderful";
    }
}

$myClass = new MyShowUserDecorator2(new MyShowUserDecorator(new MyShowUser()));

Services::$showUsers = new MyShosUsers();
Services::$showUser = new MyShowUserDecorator2(new MyShowUserDecorator(new MyShowUser()));

Services::$showUsers->showUsers(["Alfred", "Bob", "Claire"]);
```

If you have a better solution, I will be happy to know it :)

Of course, I use the decorator pattern to use these decorators in different ways in many projects like in these exemples:

```
//no decorators
Services::$showUser = new MyShowUser();

//only the first
Services::$showUser = new MyShowUserDecorator(new MyShowUser());

//only the second
Services::$showUser = new MyShowUserDecorator2(new MyShowUser());
```

So the extend not seems to be a good solution.

Thanks a lot again for giving the right way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you need to re-think this a bit. If you can provide a clear picture of what you're trying to accomplish then we can provide more insight. But to answer your question directly you can `extend` the class and then `override` the method.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61c33b0ce98631986134bf78efcd0391f9b9ab67

```
<?php
interface MyInterface {
    function showUsers($array);
    function showUser($i);
}

class MyCLass implements MyInterface {

    function showUsers($array = ["Alfred", "Bob", "Claire"])
    {
        foreach($array as $toto) {
            $this->showUser($toto);
        }
    }

    function showUser($i)
    {
        echo $i;
    }
}

// Extend the class in order to override the methods.
class MyCLassDecorator extends MyCLass {

    // Also, try removing this method to see what it does. 
    function showUsers($array = [1,2,3])
    {
        foreach($array as $toto) {
            $this->showUser($toto);
        }
    }

    function showUser($i)
    {
        echo "c'est la fete chez $i";
    }
}

$myClass = new MyCLassDecorator();

$myClass->showUsers();
```

*EDIT*

Not sure if I'm being clear or not but the issue is you're expecting *inheritance behaviour* without using *inheritance*. How is `MyCLass` supposed to know about `MyCLassDecorator::showUser`?

```
foreach($array as $toto) {
    // The issue is this line. You're mixing `decorator` and `inheritance`. 
    // You should re-think your design. This will not work.
    $this->showUser($toto);
}
```

Comment: Yes, in this little example it would be a good way to fix it, but I've got this problem in symfony services with a lot more complexe functions and more decoration encapsulation. So i need to keep the decorator pattern to avoid erasing the overridings.

Comment: You're not using the decorator pattern correctly and you've edited your code so my example is outdated now.  You're calling `$this->inner->showUsers($array);` which is calling `showUsers` on an instance of `MyCLass` that's why it is not using `MyCLassDecorator::showUser`. You have to either `extend` the class so it knows about overriden methods or you need to use the decorator pattern correctly. I'll see if I can come up with a example.

Comment: I've edited my post, you'll now maybe better understand what I need :)
And I precise that I don't know before which order the decorators will be used.